# how do I set up my angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http, frontend

I'm just messing around with angular a bit and I built a simple task API. This api has assigned and accepted tasks. Now when building the app I have these routes:

```
TaskManager.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/:username/assigned-tasks', {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/assigned-tasks.html',
                controller: 'TaskController'
            }).
            when('/:username/accepted-tasks', {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/assigned-tasks.html',
                controller: 'TaskController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                 redirectTo: '/'
            });
   }]);
```

And here is the task controller I started building and then realized this was not going to work

```
TaskManager.controller('TaskController', ['$scope', 'AssignedTasksService', function($scope, AssignedTasksService)
{
    $scope.tasks = [];

    loadAssignedTasks();

    function applyRemoteData( Tasks ) {
        $scope.tasks = Tasks;
    }

    function loadAssignedTasks() {

        AssignedTasksService.getAssignedTasks()
            .then(
            function( tasks ) {
                applyRemoteData( tasks );
            }
        );
    }
}]);
```

The getAssignedTasks funciton is just a function that runs a http get request to the api url and either returns and error or the api data

now as you can see the assigned tasks are automatically loaded once it hits the TaskController which is obviously a problem since I need to also be able to get accepted tasks. Now do I need to create a separate controller for accepted tasks or is there a way for maybe me to check the url from the controller and from there I can decide if I want to run the loadAssignedTasks function or the loadAcceptedTasks (which I haven't created yet). but it would just do the same thing as the loadAssignedTasks function but for the accepted tasks

Comment: you can inject your `$routeProvider` into the controller and check the url there. or inject a different service for different routes.

Comment: @akonsu and from there run an if statement to decide what function to run?

Comment: well, if you inject `$routeProvider` then yes, and if you inject a different service for different routes you can make them have the same methods and just call this method.

Comment: There are many ways to hack this, but ideally you'd look at your whole app (or module) as a TaskManager and all its controllers as subcomponents of it. So instead of one super controller for the whole module, I'd suggest using multiple controllers (two in your example).

Comment: hmm, didn't I give some hints on this already.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there are multiple ways to solve. All depending on current use case. But you should probably use seperate controllers to solve this problem. Also inject the data(tasks) into the controller rather than fetching them inside the controller. Consider the following example:

```
var resolveAssignedTasks = function(AssignedTasksService) {
    return AssignedTasksService.getAssignedTasks();
};

var resolveAcceptedTasks = function(AcceptedTasksService) {
    return AcceptedTasksService.getAcceptedTasks();
};

TaskManager.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/:username/assigned-tasks', {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/assigned-tasks.html',
                controller: 'TaskController',
                resolve: {
                    tasks: resolveAssignedTasks
                }
            }).
            when('/:username/accepted-tasks', {
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/assigned-tasks.html',
                controller: 'TaskController',
                resolve: {
                    tasks: resolveAssignedTasks
                }
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
```

Controllers:

```
TaskManager.controller('AssignedTaskController', ['$scope', 'tasks', function($scope, tasks)
{
     $scope.tasks = tasks;
}]);

TaskManager.controller('AcceptedTaskController', ['$scope', 'tasks', function($scope, tasks)
{
     $scope.tasks = tasks;
}]);
```

You could also by doing this use a single controller by merging the resolveFunctions into one function that returns the appropriate tasks depending on the current route. Hope this helps.